# Can you save R code files with .RData objects for version control?

Tags: r

There is no version control at my work (we have an outdated, centralized system with sensitive patient information, so we can't save things outside of it). When I save a .RData file from a script, I would like to be able to save the exact version of that .R file with it at that time. Is there a way to do this?
E.g. if I have an R script "run_analysis.R" that has the line

```
save(data,file='foo.RData')
```

Is there a way I can do something like

```
save(data,run_analysis.R,file='foo.RData')
```

so that if I pull up the data file a year later I'll know exactly what code was used to create it?

Comment: You could use `readLines()` to read a file as a character vector and store that in the Rdata file. You can only store R objects inside the Rdata file so it needs to be some variable in your workspace.

Answer (score 4):

you could zip the foo.RData file together with the run_analysis.R file and store the zipped file.

the CRAN package [zip] (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zip/zip.pdf) can be used to create the zip file from within r.

Comment: I would add that it probably makes sense to include a knitted version of `run_analysis.R` with `sessionInfo()` at the bottom into the zip as well so it can really be reproduced.